# Can't train model from checkpoint on Google Colab as session expires

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab for finetuning a pre-trained model.

I successfully preprocessed a dataset and created an instance of the Seq2SeqTrainer class:

```py
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics
)
```

The problem is training it from last checkpoint after the session is over.

If I run `trainer.train()`, it runs correctly. As it takes a long time, I sometimes came back to the Colab tab after a few hours, and I know that if the session has crashed I can continue training from the last checkpoint like this: `trainer.train("checkpoint-5500")`

The checkpoint data does no longer exist on Google Colab if I come back too late, so even though I know the point the training has reached, I will have to start all over again.

Is there any way to solve this problem? i.e. extend the session?

Comment: have you thought of saving your checkpoints outside of colab (if you're set on using colab so maybe on your drive) and when you come back just load them?

Comment: Thank you, There was a much simpler solution than I thought!. Thanks again!

Comment: saving the checkpoint helped you? if so I'll formulate an answer you can accept for future developers that may come here

Comment: yes, setting output directory as Google Drive path when creating an instance of the Seq2SeqTrainingArguments solved the problem I had. yeah I will accept ur answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem try adding a full fixed path, for example for your google drive and saving the `checkpoint-5500` to it.

Using your trainer you can set the  output directory as your Google Drive path when creating an instance of the Seq2SeqTrainingArguments.

When you come back to your code, if the session is indeed over you'll just need to load your `checkpoint-5500` from your google drive instead of retraining everything.

Add the following code:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

And then after your `trainer.train("checkpoint-5500")` is finished (or as it's last step) save your checkpoint to your google drive.
Or if you prefer, you can add a `callback` inside your fit function in order to save and update after every single epoch (that was if for some reason the session is crashing before it finish you'll still have some progress saved).